# Schemas used in Views

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration

I have a schema in postgresql, there are multiple views in that schema and those views use multiple schemas in their definition. How can I list all the schema names used by the views in that particular schema

Comment: Through `pg_depend`. Find the rewrite rule for the view, find the tables, functions etc. on which it depends, then find their schemas. Note that an exhaustive solution will be complicated and will involve a recursive query, since views can be defined on views.